# HikariConfig DEBUG messages log4j

Tags: java, hibernate, intellij-idea, log4j, hikaricp

For a long time, I am seeing this messages in the console

```
15:58:57.622 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - ScraperPool - configuration:
15:58:57.627 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - allowPoolSuspension.............false
15:58:57.627 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - autoCommit......................true
15:58:57.627 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - 15:58:57.627 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - connectionInitSql...............none
15:58:57.627 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - connectionTestQuery.............none
15:58:57.627 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - connectionTimeout...............10000
15:58:57.627 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - dataSource......................none
15:58:57.627 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - dataSourceClassName.............none
15:58:57.627 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - dataSourceJNDI..................none
15:58:57.628 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - dataSourceProperties............{password=<masked>, prepStmtCacheSqlLimit=2048, cachePrepStmts=true, prepStmtCacheSize=250, leakDetectionThreshold=15000}
15:58:57.628 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - driverClassName.................none
15:58:57.628 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - exceptionOverrideClassName......none
15:58:57.628 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - healthCheckProperties...........{}
15:58:57.628 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - healthCheckRegistry.............none
15:58:57.628 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - idleTimeout.....................10000
15:58:57.628 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - initializationFailTimeout.......1
15:58:57.628 [main] DEBUG com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig - isolateInternalQueries..........false
```

I tried to hide them with the configuration files. I didn't work. I couldn't find any solution to hide those messages.

Here is the libraries that I am having the problem with;

```
<Logger name="org.openqa.selenium" level="ERROR" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="File"/>
        </Logger>

        <Logger name="org.apache.http" level="ERROR" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="File"/>
        </Logger>

        <Logger name="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig" level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="File"/>
        </Logger>


        <logger name="org.hibernate">
            <level value="info"/>
        </logger>
```

I am having same problems with the other libraries, for example Apache HTTP, it is also printing lots of debug and unnecessary messages.

I am looking for a solution , thanks..

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=OFF
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender

log4j.logger.nz.ac.massey.cs.sdc.log4jassignment.s06005586.MemoryAppender = ERROR, MEMORY_APPENDER
log4j.additivity.nz.ac.massey.cs.sdc.log4jassignment.s06005586.MemoryAppender = false

# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=logs\\logging.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n


# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

log4j.logger.org.hibernate=OFF
log4j.logger.org.openqa.selenium = SEVERE
log4j.logger.com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig = OFF
```

Comment: check your logging, maybe you use also log4j2/slf4j configuration

Comment: @user7294900 yes I have , but what do I need to do ?

Comment: you may be to add configuration to log4j2.xml

Comment: Do you have a log4j2.properties file in your classpath? If so the configuration will be loaded from that file, not from log4j2.xml

Comment: @Guillaume I added it into my question

Answer (score 1):

To remove log HikariCP details simply add in application.properties the following settings:

**logging.level.com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig=INFO
logging.level.com.zaxxer.hikari=INFO**

If you need a deeper level of details then replace INFO with TRACE. For DEBUG log change INFO to DEBUG

Answer (score 0):

If you use [log4j2.properties](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html) define the logger per package:

```
logger.hikari.name = com.zaxxer.hikari
logger.hikari.level = error
```